# Nokia Here javascript geocoding not returning english address

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am starting to use the Nokia Maps API and have noticed some oddities when geocoding addresses (getting the Lat/Long of an address).

I was searching for "**1348 Louvain-la-Neuve,Belgium,Belgium**"

which returned me one result in the array with an address and a position; Unfortunately the address returned appears to be in French, rather than my natural locale of English.

the address portion of the return, returned me a country value of "**Belgique**" instead of an expected "**Belgium**".  Is there a way of forcing through my English locale rather than what seems to be the locale of the searched for country.

(I also realise that this might not be a locale issue but rather official name of the country, which is still an issue for me as i deal in English)

Comment: Nokia here? Like, the whole company?

Comment: Nokia have a platform for maps and such called "HERE" http://developer.here.com/en_GB

Comment: OK :) didn't know that, thanks... turned up as a funny pun.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug (ticket no: JSLA-3608). It should be the case that adding `nokia.Settings.set("defaultLanguage", "en-GB");`  alters the locale of the geocode request, but it looks to me like the geocode function is not passing the locale to the geocoding service.  Funnily enough, the reverseGeocoding service **does** pass the locale correctly, so it is possible to use a workaround to obtain the preferred locale:

```
searchManager.geoCode({
        searchTerm: "1348 Louvain-la-Neuve,Belgium,Belgium",
        onComplete: function (data, requestStatus, requestId) {
            processResults(data, requestStatus, requestId);
            map.zoomTo(addressesContainer.getBoundingBox());
            }
    });
```

returns "Belgique"

whereas:

```
searchManager.geoCode({
        searchTerm: "1348 Louvain-la-Neuve,Belgium,Belgium",
        onComplete: function (data, requestStatus, requestId) {
                    nokia.places.search.manager.reverseGeoCode({
                    latitude: data.location.position.latitude,
                    longitude: data.location.position.longitude,
                    onComplete: function (data, status) {
                         processResults(data, requestStatus, requestId);
                        map.zoomTo(addressesContainer.getBoundingBox());
                    }
                });             
            }
    });
```

returns  "Belgium".

Here is an example in full (use your own [app id and token](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_Obtain_Your_Own_Nokia_appID_and_Token))

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=EmulateIE9; IE=EmulateIE10;"/>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <title>Nokia Maps API for JavaScript Example: Addresses</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Geocode multiple addresses and display them using standard markers and infobubbles"/>
            <meta name="keywords" content="addresses, services, geocode, reverse, geocode"/>
            <!-- For scaling content for mobile devices, setting the viewport to the width of the device-->
            <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
            <!-- Styling for example container (NoteContainer & Logger)  -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/templates/js/exampleHelpers.css"/>
            <!-- By default we add ?with=all to load every package available, it's better to change this parameter to your use case. Options ?with=maps|positioning|places|placesdata|directions|datarendering|all -->
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.4/jsl.js?with=all"></script>
            <!-- JavaScript for example container (NoteContainer & Logger)  -->

            <style type="text/css">
                html {
                    overflow:hidden;
                }

                body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    position: absolute;
                }

                #mapContainer {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    left: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="mapContainer"></div>
            <div id="uiContainer"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" id="exampleJsSource">
    /*  Set authentication token and appid 
    *   WARNING: this is a demo-only key
    *   please register on http://api.developer.nokia.com/ 
    *   and obtain your own developer's API key 
    */
    nokia.Settings.set("appId", "APP ID); 
    nokia.Settings.set("authenticationToken", "TOKEN");
    nokia.Settings.set("defaultLanguage", "en-GB");

    // Get the DOM node to which we will append the map
    var mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");

    // We create a new instance of InfoBubbles bound to a variable so we can call it later on
    var infoBubbles = new nokia.maps.map.component.InfoBubbles();

    // Create a map inside the map container DOM node
    var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
        // initial center and zoom level of the map
        center: [52.51, 13.4],
        zoomLevel: 10,
        components:[
            // We add the behavior component to allow panning / zooming of the map
            new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
            infoBubbles
        ]
    });

    var location2,

        // We will put our address markers into this container zo we can zoom in to the markers
        addressesContainer = new nokia.maps.map.Container(),
        marker,
        searchCenter = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(52.51, 13.4),
        searchManager = nokia.places.search.manager;

    map.objects.add(addressesContainer);

    var processResults = function (data, requestStatus, requestId) {
        // Data is instance of nokia.places.objects.Place 
        var location = data.location;
        // Ensure that we our request came back with valid result
        if (requestStatus == "OK") {
            // Create a new marker on the found location
            marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(location.position);
            // Add marker to its container so it will be render
            addressesContainer.objects.add(marker); 
            marker.$address = location.address;
            marker.$label = data.name;
        }
    };

    /*
        searchManager.geoCode({
            searchTerm: "1348 Louvain-la-Neuve,Belgium,Belgium",
            onComplete: function (data, requestStatus, requestId) {
                processResults(data, requestStatus, requestId);
                map.zoomTo(addressesContainer.getBoundingBox());
                }
        }); */


        searchManager.geoCode({
            searchTerm: "1348 Louvain-la-Neuve,Belgium,Belgium",
            onComplete: function (data, requestStatus, requestId) {
                        nokia.places.search.manager.reverseGeoCode({
                        latitude: data.location.position.latitude,
                        longitude: data.location.position.longitude,
                        onComplete: function (data, status) {
                             processResults(data, requestStatus, requestId);
                            map.zoomTo(addressesContainer.getBoundingBox());
                        }
                    });             
                }
        }); 


    addressesContainer.addListener("click", function (evt) {
        var marker = evt.target,
            address = marker.$address,
            label = marker.$label;  
        if (marker instanceof nokia.maps.map.Marker) {
            infoBubbles.openBubble(label, marker.coordinate);
        }

    });




            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The current HERE Maps version (2.5.3) seems to have the same bug, is it possible?